# AVPlayer is not working when I'm trying to use with this YTVimeoExtractor

Tags: swift, github, avplayer, vimeo, avkit

When I try to play the video through the AVPlayer, the video loads for some time(the loading symbol appears at the top of the player) then suddenly it stops and the play icon with a crossover is shown. Don't know what is wrong? I can get the video informations but I can't make the video to play.
I will show what I have done. Could anyone answer my question, help is much appreciated.

```
import UIKit
import AVKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

var playerVC : AVPlayerViewController!
var playerItem : AVPlayerItem!
var player : AVPlayer!
var playerLayer: AVPlayerLayer!


@IBOutlet weak var videoURL: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var videoTitle: UILabel!
@IBAction func playVideo(sender: AnyObject) {

    YTVimeoExtractor.sharedExtractor().fetchVideoWithVimeoURL(self.videoURL.text!, withReferer: nil, completionHandler: {(video, error) -> Void in

        if video != nil {


            // https://vimeo.com/165891648
            self.videoTitle.text = video?.title

            print("hello: \(self.videoTitle.text)")

            let url = NSURL(string: self.videoURL.text!)


//                let url = NSURL.init(fileURLWithPath: self.videoURL.text!)

            self.playerItem = AVPlayerItem.init(URL: url!)
            self.player = AVPlayer.init(playerItem: self.playerItem)
            self.playerVC = AVPlayerViewController.init();
            self.playerVC.player = self.player;
            self.player.currentItem!.playbackLikelyToKeepUp

            self.presentViewController(self.playerVC, animated: true) { () -> Void in
                self.playerVC.player?.play()
            }

        }else {

            let alert = UIAlertController(title: error!.localizedDescription, message:  error!.localizedFailureReason, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
            self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

        }

    })



}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

        }

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
   }    
}
```

This is the one I get on the simulator.

[image]

I used this https://github.com/lilfaf/YTVimeoExtractor one to do this sample project. You can try it out and let me know.

Comment: what is the value of             self.videoTitle.text = video?.title

Comment: it is the title of the video

Comment: and what is the url ?

Comment: it is the the video url, i give it in the text field and click the play button in the simulator which will eventually play the video but certainly it is not!

Comment: we need to know the video url to check if its valid one or not.

Comment: you can see in the completion handler i'm checking that.

Comment: you are just checking if itsnt = nil. not every format can be played on iOS etc. if you can give the url that would be helpful. otherwise i see myself only wasting time with you not cooperating.

Comment: the url i commented is the one, whatever the url you give, the library will assign it to the video variable which is of type YTVimeoVideo!

Comment: https://vimeo.com/165891648 is not a link to a video but to a webpage having a video. so the url will fail in AVPlayer

Comment: then how do i get the video url in vimeo?!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and fix using this way:

```
      @IBAction func btnDownload_touchUpInside(_ sender: UIButton) {

        YTVimeoExtractor.shared().fetchVideo(withVimeoURL: self.videoURL.text!, withReferer: nil, completionHandler: {(video, error) -> Void in

            if video != nil {

                self.videoTitle.text = video?.title


                if let streamUrls = video?.streamURLs
                {
                    var streamURL: String?

                    var streams : [String:String] = [:]
                    for (key,value) in streamUrls {
                        streams["\(key)"] = "\(value)"
                        print("\(key) || \(value)")
                    }
                    if let large = streams["720"]
                    {
                        streamURL = large
                    }
                    else if let high = streams["480"]
                    {
                        streamURL = high
                    }
                    else if let medium = streams["360"]
                    {
                        streamURL = medium
                    }
                    else if let low = streams["270"]
                    {
                        streamURL = low
                    }

                    if let url = streamURL
                    {
                        Alamofire.download(url, to: { (temporaryURL, response) -> (destinationURL: URL, options: DownloadRequest.DownloadOptions) in
                            if let directoryURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0] as? NSURL {

                                let fileName = response.suggestedFilename!
                                let finalPath = directoryURL.appendingPathComponent(fileName)
                                self.downloadedVideoPath = finalPath?.absoluteString
                                return (finalPath!, DownloadRequest.DownloadOptions(rawValue: 2))

                            }
                        }).downloadProgress(closure: { (progress) in
                            print("Progress: \(progress.fractionCompleted)")
                        })

                    }
                }
            }
        })
    }

    @IBAction func btnPlayOffLine_touchUpInside(_ sender: UIButton) {
        YTVimeoExtractor.shared().fetchVideo(withVimeoURL: self.videoURL.text!, withReferer: nil, completionHandler: {(video, error) -> Void in

            if video != nil {

                let videoURL = NSURL(string: self.downloadedVideoPath!)
                let player = AVPlayer(url: videoURL! as URL)
                let playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
                playerViewController.player = player
                self.present(playerViewController, animated: true) {
                    playerViewController.player!.play()

                }
            }
        })
    }

    @IBAction func btnPlayOnLine_touchUpInside(_ sender: UIButton) {


        YTVimeoExtractor.shared().fetchVideo(withVimeoURL: self.videoURL.text!, withReferer: nil, completionHandler: {(video, error) -> Void in

            if video != nil {

                self.videoTitle.text = video?.title


                if let streamUrls = video?.streamURLs
                {
                    var streamURL: String?

                    var streams : [String:String] = [:]
                    for (key,value) in streamUrls {
                        streams["\(key)"] = "\(value)"
                        print("\(key) || \(value)")
                    }
                    if let large = streams["720"]
                    {
                        streamURL = large
                    }
                    else if let high = streams["480"]
                    {
                        streamURL = high
                    }
                    else if let medium = streams["360"]
                    {
                        streamURL = medium
                    }
                    else if let low = streams["270"]
                    {
                        streamURL = low
                    }

                    if let url = streamURL
                    {
                        let videoURL = NSURL(string: url)
                        let player = AVPlayer(url: videoURL! as URL)
                        let playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
                        playerViewController.player = player
                        self.present(playerViewController, animated: true) {
                            playerViewController.player!.play()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        })
    }
}
```